# Efficient atomic bulk refresh operation in MariaDB for many to many relation

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, transactions, mariadb

I need to keep a list of unique pages in a `pages` table linked in a many-to-many relation with `page_providers` table via `page_xref_page_provider` table. I am having difficulty with devising an efficient atomic bulk refresh operation, consisting of the following:

1. A new list of pages is received from a page provider. Some pages on that list may be the same as already on record in the database (having the same `Url`), while some pages may be deleted from the list and some pages may be added.
2. There are some per-page statistics in the database, so I shouldn't delete an old page (identified by unique `Url`) if there is at least one page provider for whom this page is still on the list.
3. If the updated list from the current page provider doesn't contain a page it previously contained, and no other page list provider contains this page on its list, the page should be deleted from the `pages` table.
4. Pages that are not on record by the moment I receive the page list, must be added to `pages` table and cross-referenced in `page_xref_page_provider`

What I have tried:

```
-- We use IGNORE to handle duplicate URLs on the list we received from the current page provider
-- pages_temp is a temporary table whose creation I have omitted
INSERT IGNORE INTO pages_temp (Url, Host, Port) VALUES (?, ?, ?);

BEGIN;

-- In the DB client program, we get the last inserted ID from the following query and the number of
--   rows affected, so to get a range of newly inserted IDs
INSERT IGNORE INTO pages (Url, Host, Port) SELECT Url, Host, Port FROM pages_temp;

-- This doesn't work (wrong syntax), could you correct me here?
-- When preparing this statement, we parameterize it with the current PageProviderID, the
--   last inserted ID (which is actually the first ID in the bulk) and the number of rows inserted
--   plus the first ID in the bulk.
INSERT INTO page_xref_page_provider (PageProviderID, PageID) SELECT ?, i BETWEEN ? AND ?;

-- This query is parametrized with the current page provider ID
DELETE page_xref_page_provider FROM page_xref_page_provider AS pxpp
JOIN pages ON pxpp.PageID = pages.ID AND pxpp.PageProviderID=?
WHERE pages.Url NOT IN (SELECT Url FROM pages_temp);

-- This seems inefficient because the subquery also fetch the relations not affected by the current
--   list of pages / page provider
DELETE FROM pages WHERE pages.ID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT PageID FROM page_xref_page_provider);

COMMIT;
```

Comment: This might be a better question over on [DBA Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1):

Avoid `NOT IN ( SELECT ... )`.  In some situations, its performance is terrible.  `LEFT JOIN` and `EXISTS` may work faster.

Are there `AUTO_INCREMENT` ids in the tables?  If so, beware of `IGNORE` "burning ids".

Here is a discussion of a high-speed ingestion technique:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table

Performance tips on many-to-many tables:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table